# HP Pavilion 15 with AMD dual graphics - Ubuntu live environment not starting

Tags: boot, ati, graphics, 13.10, hp-pavilion

I've had this laptop for about a day now and have decided to try Ubuntu on it and determine if I want to install it. I created a USB, it booted (Secure Boot was on, I tried with Secure Boot off to no effect), and then the problem occurred.

The screen turned off for a second, turned back on to a black screen, shut off again and turned back on with a dialogue box telling me that the system had to use low-graphics mode.  I clicked OK, selected low-graphics mode from the menu and clicked OK. The screen switched to the boot messages and did not go any further than this. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> started rebooting the laptop though.

I tried booting again, but this time I edited the boot options in GRUB to add `nomodeset`. This time, the laptop only booted to a black screen. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> took me to a prompt, I tried `startx` from there, but X didn't start, complaining that it wanted kernel mode setting back.

I can not seem to find any option to disable one graphics chip or the other in the UEFI setup menus.

> Laptop : HP Pavilion 15-E004AU.
>
> The CPU : AMD A6-4400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
>
> The graphics chip : AMD Radeon HD 7520G + 8670M Dual Graphics.
>
> The Ubuntu version : 13.10, 64 bit.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I tried 12.04.3 LTS, it managed to bring the desktop up. There are severe graphics glitches after about two minutes though.

Comment: would you try xubuntu? http://xubuntu.org/

Comment: This just produced an error screen that started with ` ==== START =====
divide error: 0000 [#1] SMP `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one solution that solved this for me was trying Ubuntu 14.04's Beta 1 image, written to a USB. It booted from this image to the live environment without any issues whatsoever, and installation worked perfectly. After reboot, it booted from the HDD, then rebooted itself twice. After that, I was able to log in and use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar issue with Ubuntu 13.10 on HP Pavilion 17-e050sm laptop:

Microprocessor AMD Quad-Core A4-5000M APU with Radeon HD 8330 Graphics (1.5 GHz, 2 MB cache) 
Chipset AMD A76M FCH 
Memory 4 GB DDR3 
Video Graphics AMD Radeon HD 8330 Graphics (up to 1.98 GB)

and solved it by passing **nomodereset** kernel option (press F6) before booting live session.
Hope it helps you,

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I could solving for ubuntu 14.04 in hp pavillion by installing fglrx
HP Pavillion is is AMD/Intel Hybrid system, so switch to shell mode and install fglrx and fglrx-pxpress:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```